# 17.10 menu bar missing

Tags: gnome, menu

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 but I don't have a menu bar(The bar with file, edit, etc..). When I press the `alt` key in Firefox, the menu bar appears for less than a second.

How can I get the menu bar back?

Comment: Which applications did you try? Many hide it by default and only toggle it with the Alt key (e. g. Firefox and Nautilus). Also verify that the Alt key on your keyboard works reliably.

Comment: The architect of the desktop is diferent, so you need a diferent client application. In xorg and for now (as please see is discontinued), you can install this extension: https://github.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu Search on google what package you need  to install it or in the readme file.

Comment: How is this closed?  I had exactly the same question when I tried out 17.10 and launched firefox ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox simply pressing Alt once is enough to bring the menu bar back. You probably are wondering about the merged menu that used to exist in 16.04, that one is gone for the moment.

As a side note, that's the default behaviour of Firefox's menu bar. The reason why 16.04 had was, I think, because of the Hud? Which is now gone from 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask only about Firefox you can click `<Alt>`, select *View* `<v>`, then *Toolbars* `<t>`, check *Menu Bar* `<m>` checkbox.